# No video when enabling Compatibility Support Module (CSM) in UEFI Setup

Tags: motherboard, bios, uefi

I'm having a problem where I can't boot into Unraids GUI mode. Apparently this is caused by UEFI boot and Compatability Support Module (CSM) needs to be switched on to allow it to work. [(Source)](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/73512-unable-to-boot-into-gui-mode/?do=findComment&comment=676569)

However when diving into the [ASRock B460M Steel Legend](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/B460M%20Steel%20Legend/index.asp) UEFI Setup and switching on CSM I get no video output at all both on the [Intel i5 10500](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/199277/intel-core-i5-10500-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-50-ghz.html) iGPU or the [Nvidia Geforce 1050ti](https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Graphics-Card/GV-N105TD5-4GD#kf). I have tried all of the video ports on both except for the Display Ports which I dont have an adapter for. To restore video I have to clear the CMOS using the jumper pins.

I have also tried running the system on the integrated graphics only to no avail.

I updated the firmware of the BIOS from v1.10 to v1.40, this seemed to add a check when enabling CSM to only allow it to run when a dedicated GPU is installed but I'm still having problems. [(Source)](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/B460M%20Steel%20Legend/index.asp#BIOS)

There are three settings when enabling it:

- Launch PXE OpROM Policy
- Launch Storage OpROM Policy
- Other PCI Device ROM Priority

Each of the three settings have these options:

- UEFI Only
- Legacy Only
- Disabled

[CSM Documentation (Page 87)](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/B460M%20Steel%20Legend.pdf)

I dont fully understand what CSM does or what each of the options do. If anyone could shed some light on this problem that woud be great! Thank you.

Comment: CSM allows for a Legacy or UEFI boot configuration

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for that! Do you know why a dedicated GPU is required when using CSM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to get video to display when CSM is enabled.

I set all of the above options to disabled while keeping CSM enabled.  Not sure how helpful it was but I also set the boot image to `Disabled` at the same time so it now displays POST messages. I notice I can only get video to display via the GPU even though the primary GPU is set to `Onboard` and the iGPU Multi is set to `Enabled`. I only need CSM enabled temporarily so it isn't a huge issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some PCI devices like graphic cards require additional 'drivers' to work at the BIOS stage.

But BIOS is not an OS, it can't have all the drivers for all the possible PCI devices that you can plug into your board.
To solve this problem such complex PCI devices store its 'driver' it its own firmware. This is a concept known as a PCI Option ROM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_ROM

BIOS queries PCI configuration space in every PCI device and determines if it has an option ROM. If it has BIOS can execute code from the option ROM depending on the BIOS settings.

PCI Option ROM can have several code images in itself. The common case is that option ROM contain two images:

- driver for legacy BIOS (Legacy OpROM)
- driver for UEFI BIOS   (UEFI OpROM)

Keep in mind that older cards can contain only `driver for legacy BIOS`, newer/future ones can contain only `driver for UEFI BIOS`.

Currently the world is in the transition process from Legacy BIOS interface to UEFI. UEFI firmware doesn't work with Legacy OpROMs. But for now vendors still leave a possibility to work with such legacy interfaces via CSM mode.

But you wouldn't see any output, if you set a BIOS policy to load only UEFI OpROMs, but your graphic card only contains Legacy OpROM

Answer (score 0):

This is ridiculous. It seems disabling CSM and enabling Secure Boot on BIOS triggers something and it makes some hardware stop working properly, in my case it was GPU, it can't be used on UEFI (BIOS) environment, though I check my GPU on GPU-Z and other website it supports UEFI, but it's still goes blank and straight go to Windows.

When on Windows, some hardware also behave strangely, LAN and Bluetooth for my case, I cant use the internet because the Ethernet port is not detected at all, and I don't have wifi for my PC. Also Bluetooth dongle can't be used.

I tried boot to UEFI from Windows Update / Advanced Startup, still nothing shows. Pushing F2 button (my default key for BIOS) while boot also shows nothing. I also tried cable method both HDMI and DVI in all GPU ports, it's not working, I don't have integrated GPU on my CPU and I don't want to borrow iGPU from someone and test it on my PC, to much hassle to find CPU donor, repaste and all that stuff.

As someone else suggest, I remove CMOS battery, wait for 10 minutes just in case there's still electricity on the capacitors. After 10 mins, I plug CMOS battery back in, and it resets all the BIOS settings (XMP, Fans, etc), but this is the only way, at least for my case.

Finally!

In some cases I read on internet (yes it's known problem), even reseting BIOS isn't reversing that CMS and secure boot settings, glad my case isn't like that troublesome.

My specs: Ryzen 5 3600 (no iGPU), AsRock B450M Steel Legend latest bios version 4.60, 16 GB RAM 3200Mhz, Radeon RX 580 4GB Sapphire Nitro.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).